# iOS Autolayout constraints for label

Tags: ios7

How to set constraints to a label on imageview to display it at same position on all devices.Please check the image. The red label should be in the white empty box in image.
Thnx in advance.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTGGR.png)

Comment: check autolayout tutorials..

Comment: Thnx.But i checked it and tried to solve almost for 2 days,but not working.Check image description to see image.